# NuxtJS & SASS Loader - Build with sass-loader (SCSS) on production

Tags: webpack, vue.js, sass, nuxt.js, sass-loader

I've added this lines to build with sass-loader on development (local) server:

**nuxt.config.js**

```
module.exports = {

  mode: 'spa',

  build: {
    analyze: {
      analyzerMode: 'static',
      generateStatsFile: true,
      statsFilename: 'webpack-stats.json',
      openAnalyzer: false
    },
    vendor: [
      'axios',
      'vuetify'
    ],
    extend (config) {
      config.resolve.alias['vue'] = 'vue/dist/vue.common'
      const vueLoader = config.module.rules.find((rule) => rule.loader === 'vue-loader')
      vueLoader.options.loaders.scss = 'vue-style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader?' + JSON.stringify({
        includePaths: [
          path.resolve(__dirname), 'node_modules'
        ]
      })
    }
  }

  ...
}
```

The problem is on production, I've this error:

> Cannot find module "!!vue-style-loader!css-loader!../../../node_modules/vue-loader/lib/style-compiler/index?{"vue":true,"id":"data-v-7ef06ffa","scoped":true,"hasInlineConfig":true}!sass-loader?{"includePaths":["/app/config","node_modules"]}!../../../node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector?type=styles&index=0!./index.vue"

<sub>*This question is available on [Nuxt.js](https://nuxtjs.cmty.io) community ([#c6871](https://nuxtjs.cmty.io/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/c6871))*</sub>

Comment: you are facing this issue only on production ? no issue in development environment is it?

Comment: Yes issue only on production.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I haven't need of this config on **nuxt.config.js**, just install **sass-loader** and **node-sass** in "dependencies", not in "devDependencies".