# Why can't I build this nuxtjs app inside docker, while local builds work?

Tags: webpack, sass, nuxt.js

I'm developing this nuxtjs project on a Mac (all the latest and greatest) and local builds and generation work fine. I'm using `sass-loader` as a dev dependency, and my `nuxt.config.js` file is not very different from the default:

```
module.exports = {
  head: {
    title: 'temp-www',
    meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
      { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
      { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: 'Nuxt.js project' }
    ],
    link: [
      { rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' }
    ]
  },
  modules: [
    [ 'nuxt-fontawesome', {
      component: 'fa',
      imports: [
        { set: '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free-brands' },
      ]
    }],
  ],
  loading: { color: '#3B8070' },
  build: {
    extend (config, { isDev, isClient }) {
      if (isDev && isClient) {
        config.module.rules.push({
          enforce: 'pre',
          test: /\.(js|vue)$/,
          loader: 'eslint-loader',
          exclude: /(node_modules)/
        })
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I then created a `Dockerfile` like this

```
FROM node:stretch

ENV NODE_ENV=production
ENV HOST=0.0.0.0

RUN mkdir -p /app
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app

EXPOSE 3000

RUN npm install
RUN npm run build
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

(and appropriate `.dockerignore`) but I get the following error while building the image.

```
ERROR in ./layouts/default.vue
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'sass-loader' in '/app/layouts'
 @ ./layouts/default.vue 2:2-436
 @ ./.nuxt/App.js
 @ ./.nuxt/index.js
 @ ./.nuxt/client.js
```

In there, and in other `.vue` files, I use sass in a block like `<style lang="scss">`. I tried changing that to `sass` but it makes no difference.

Strangely, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49735461/nuxtjs-sass-loader-build-with-sass-loader-scss-on-production) says it should work by making `sass-loader` and `node-sass` as runtime deps, not devtime deps. I skeptically tried that, and it got worse, until I changed the `lang` attribute in the `style` blocks to `scss` instead of `sass`. In this case, and this case only, I got the image built correctly.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to install `sass-loader` for webpack:

```
npm install sass-loader --save-dev
```

(see the official doc about "How to use pre-processors" (eg. sass): https://nuxtjs.org/faq/pre-processors/ )

---

But setting environment variable NODE_ENV to "production" causes `npm install` to ignore devDependencies.

So you can install as main dependency:

```
npm install sass-loader --save
```

---

The right way is to continue using as dev dependency and build your app on CI and then deploy it on your production env with NODE_ENV "production"

Comment: (I am using `sass-loader`). By doing what you suggest, I would still need to include the `node_modules` directory, or at least the modules that are specified in `nuxt.config.js`. The alternative is to `generate` and serve as static files. I would prefer to use the `build` rather than the `generate`d code, if possible.

Comment: and you have install sass-loader  as dependency  (`--save`) or devDependency (`--save-dev`) ? If you want use NODE_ENV "production", you have to use `--save` as explain before. About my last suggestion, it's just a philosophy from continuous delivery "Build binaries only once, Deploy anywhere". Make a complete `build` with node_modules with a CI platform (Jenkins, Travis, GitlabCI), and deploy it every where :)

Comment: `sass-loader` was a devDependency, and I was making a `build`. The problem, as you say, is that devDependencies are ignored in `production` – which I hadn't considered, I thought it was more like a build-time/run-time thing. The problem with `build`ing, whether locally or in CI, is that webpack has `modules` in its config that need to be available at run-time. In my case, `sass` was not an issue, because once building was done, it was done. However, I has a module in webpack's modules. Isn't there a way of telling webpack to pull these modules into the build? `nuxt generate` seems to do it.

Comment: I'm confused, I re-did a `build` inside Docker and I didn't have issues with stuff needing to be in `node_modules`. I must have done something wrong yesterday.